# How do I return the value after checking for a condition?

Tags: if-statement, return, verilog

The following code has to check for an 'e' value such that the gcd(h,e)=1. Where 1

```
module great(p,q,e,d);
input p,q;
output e,d;
reg e,d;
h=((p-1)*(q-1));
always 
begin
for(e=2;e<h;e=e+1)
begin
g1=gcd(h,e);
if(g1==1)
return e;
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please take a few minutes to read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  It will help you get an answer to this question.  In general, try to make it easy for the reader to understand what you are asking.  Some indentation would help, in this case, along with what you tried, what it did, and what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

If, by "return a value", you mean spit out a value you can use in another module, you would use the output of this module as your "return" value. But even ignoring the `return e`, I don't think your code will work if you tried to run it, because it is too much like a programming language. There's several major things wrong:

1. You already declared `output e,d` so you can't declare two `reg` with the same name. You probably want `output reg e,d` instead.
2. You didn't declare a type for `h` or `g1`.
3. You have a `for` loop for `e` but `e` can never be anything other than `0` or `1` because you didn't set a size for it, so by default it is only 1-bit long. Even if it was big enough that you could increment it past `1`, it's a `wire` type by default, and you can't make those kind of increments to a `wire` directly.
4. I assume `gcd` is some module you made somewhere else, but this isn't how you interconnect modules together. You can't call it like it's a function. You have to use `wire` and `reg` to connect the inputs and outputs of two modules together, almost like you're plugging components in.

Those are what stick out the most to me, anyway. I think you are coding your Verilog as if it were Python and that's what's causing these misunderstandings. Verilog is very, very different.